# How can I schedule different task within DAG with different time_frame at 2hrs interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Example, I have designed python function which will run every 2hrs -
Code -

```
def check_hour(divisor, true_task, false_task, **kwargs):
    hr = parser.isoparse(kwargs['templates_dict']['current_runtime']).hour
    check_good = (hr % divisor) == 0
    if kwargs['templates_dict']['date_passed']:
        start = int(kwargs['templates_dict']['start_time'].split(':')[0])
        end = int(kwargs['templates_dict']['end_time'].split(':')[0])
        if (hr <= end and hr >= start) and check_good:
            return true_task
        else:
            return false_task
    else:
        if check_good:
            return true_task
        else:
            return false_task
```

But this is true only for even hours.
I need to validate it with odd_hours, like one of my task will start at 13:00hrs till 01:00hrs and other at 9:00hrs tp 20:00hrs.

what can be modified to make it more generic which holds true for any start and end time?

Comment: Can you explain what the line `check_good = (hr % divisor) == 0` does?

Comment: You can use BranchPythonOperator and route different tasks to different branches as per your specified conditions. Like - if conditions for even_time are met, only even_task will run, and if conditions for odd_time are met then odd_task will run.

Comment: @mkrieger1 check_good = (hr % divisor) == 0 will check for the divisor viz., 2 in this case and return the task accordingly

Comment: @PriyaAgarwal If that could be the case I would have done long ago :D 
Here, I need to pass with the time_frame.
Anyways, I might get the solution though, just need to take care the time which is for the next day means midnight case(after 00:00)

Comment: So, if you want to accept tasks at *every* hour, not just every *two* hours, why don't you pass `divisor = 1`?

Comment: Actually, it should run at every 2hour interval but in an time frame. 
Example - If job starts at 9 then next it'll run at 11, 13 , 15 and so on.
Divisor = 1 will not suffice the requirement

Comment: And if you change `(hr % divisor) == 0` to `(hr % divisor) == 1`? Then instead of all even hours you get all odd hours. Is this not what you want?